# PHP variable in SQLite query

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm a beginner with web-related coding and I'm trying to make a web-interface from where I can read and write to the sqlite database. My current problem is implementing a PHP-variable ($inNodeID) to sqlite query:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = "$inNodeID"
```

If I replace the variable in query to the value of the variable (`"ID007"`) everything seems to work. So what is wrong with my syntax in this manner?

```
    $inNodeID = "ID007";
    echo "Requested node: $inNodeID \n";

    print "<table border=1>";
    print "<tr><td>NodeID</td><td>MemoryIndex</td><td>DataIndex</td><td>TimeStamp</td></tr>";
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = "$inNodeID"');
    //$result->bindParam(':inNodeID', $inNodeID, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
    print "<td>".$row['NodeID']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['MemoryIndex']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['DataIndex']."</td>";
    print "<td>".$row['TimeStamp']."</td></tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you were about to use the **right way** but for some reason gave up

Here you go:

```
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = ?');
$result->execute(array($inNodeID));
$data = $result->fetchAll();

foreach($data as $row)
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it! I think it was the use of '?' in the sql query that I missed in the first place.

Comment: No, you can use either way. It was the proper order of **prepare** / **execute** what you really missed

Answer (score 1):

With SQLite3, you can do it like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = ? OR NodeID = ?');
$query->bindParam(1, $yourFirstNodeID, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$query->bindParam(2, $yourSecondNodeID, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $query->execute();

var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

You can find the documentation about bindParam [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because of you have enclosed variable `$inNodeID`. If a variable is enclosed in Quotes PHP behave in different ways based on the Quote thats used. PHP evaluates a variable only when its enclosed in Double quotes, if its used with Single Quote then PHP treats it as a STRING.

please change your code to any one of the below option, your issue will be solved

Option 1

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = $inNodeID");
```

Option 2

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = '.$inNodeID);
```

For more info Check Out [PHP Manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: This would have been the simplest solution and the solution I hoped, but neither of these worked. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

you should do Three steps:

1. **prepare** your sql code with **imaginary word and ":" instead of your variable** like this:

   ```
   $statement = $db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col_test = :imaginary_word");
   ```
2. **bind** your php variable with the previous step "imaginary word" like this:

   ```
   $statement -> bindValue(':imaginary_word', $php_variable);
   ```
3. your statement which is a combination of your SQL code and PHP variables is ready and it's the time to **execute** it like this:

   ```
   $your_result = $statement -> execute();
   ```

   ♦ now you can use this "$your_result" for fetch_array() , fetch_all Or anything you want...

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to put " around the variable. So try:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE NodeID = ' . $inNodeID );
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downgraded, as it is the (or at least 'a') correct answer to the question at hand. While I agree with what @Your-Common-Sense has written, he doesn't answer the question.